# Logitech Wireless Keyboard & mouse not working after upgrade to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, keyboard, hardware, mouse

I upgraded my Dell Dimension 9200C to 12.04 Precise Pangolin with no issues, I ran it fine for a night but when I went back in a couple days later my Logitech Wireless Keyboard K350 and M510 mouse weren't active when booted.  I can boot into an older version from the main the boot screen the mouse and keyboard work, but the network stack is gone.  It says the networking manager on this version is not compatible.  I'm scratching my head, it isn't the mouse and keyboard, they work fine on my dual boot, and they load fine in Knoppix.  They did work fine on 12.04 for 1 night.  Open to suggestions before I re-install completely.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; still do. But my solution now (after other failed ones) is to de-port and then re-port the two USB receivers after the initial daily boot up; then both the wireless mouse and keyboard work fine. A very minor nuisance at worst.

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I do have similar problems. It works for a couple of minutes and then fails in most cases no matter  what. Have you check that bug?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/991932